# Do destroyed wooden chests respawn?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I was attacking the pirate ships near North Akkala and I came across a wooden chest containing a pretty powerful lizal bow, which I left because I had full inventory, and wanted to come back after the fight.

I feel I accidentally blown it up, since a TNT barrel fell near it, and after I cleared out the zone I wasn't able to find the wooden chest anymore.

So, is there any chance that a blown up/destroyed wooden chest, which I wasn't able to collect, will respawn the next Blood Moon?

Comment: In my case blood moon occured but, and I could have expected that, the pirate ships didn't respawn, and with them the wooden chest I missed. So this doesn't actually answer my question.

Comment: In BOTW, they respawned unless you picked up the item that was inside. If you picked it up, then it counted as opening the chest normally. Good chance TOTK works the same, but don’t know for sure.

Comment: @GendoIkari that's enough for me, it's probably the same